# Fredolm theory in A. Friedman's book

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

The image below is part of Fredholm theory in A. Friedman's book. This is to prove $$\dim(\ker(\lambda-T))=\dim(\ker(\lambda-T)^*).$$ I don't understand how to reach the highlighted part: $\lambda x-Tx=0$

Could anybody help? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You might be interested to know that `\dim` and `\ker` are LaTeX commands that MSE understands.  Moreover there is the `\operatorname` command, which can be used to get properly formatted operators, such as $\operatorname{arctan}(x)$ (typeset with `\operatorname{arctan}(x)`).

Comment: New here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$\lambda x-T(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} x_i^*(x)y_i$. It is an element of $Vect(y_1,...,y_n)$ The author shows that $x_i^*(x)=0, i=1,...,n$ this implies that $\lambda x-T(x)=0$ since its coordinates are zero in the basis $(y_1,...,y_n)$ of $Vect(y_1,...,y_n)$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!